# Minified JS only works by pasting source into Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm not sure if there is a clear way for me to show / describe the problem that I'm having. But here goes:

I've developed an app with AngularJS (have not put live yet). It was decided that we needed tooltips for some of the metrics on the tables. We liked the general look of [TipTip jQuery Plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin).
On my `index` file I correctly include the minified.js:

```
<script src="../assets/javascripts/app/jquery.tipTip.minified.js"></script>
```

(yes, the path is correct. I can click on the link in chrome developer tools and see the source file).

In my controller, I call it with this:

```
$scope.addTolltips = function() {
    $timeout(function(){$('.results-metrics').tipTip({maxWidth:"300px", defaultPosition: "top"});},500);
}
```

I added the `$timeout` to make sure there was enough time for dynamic stuff on the page to be load in the DOM. I know it's probably not necessary anymore though.

But when `tipTip()` is being called I get a console error:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tipTip'
```

However, if I take the minified source and paste it into my controller before the `tipTip()`, then everything works perfect. **Any thoughts?**

Comment: Give some sample on how are you calling the method.

Comment: @Chandermani Your request has been granted :)

Comment: Did you include your `<script>` element for TipTip *before* the script for angularjs?

Comment: @obecker I have tried it in a variety of places, before & after angular. Before & after jQuery (but I know it needs to be after). I've also tried it before the close of the body tag.

Comment: Yes, the order should be jQuery, TipTip, angularjs. If this doesn't work, I'm clueless.

Comment: @obecker - as am I. Hence the plea for help on S.O., haha.

Comment: What happens if you use `angular.element('.results-metrics')` instead of `$('.results-metrics')`? It looks like `$` has been changed ... (BTW - the controller is the wrong place to access the DOM.)

Comment: @obecker - you did it. angular.element is what I needed. That solved it. Go ahead and submit it as an answer and I'll accept it. Also, I know that DOM manipulation isn't best in controller, but I was having issues doing it as a directive. Now that this is solved, I may be able to get it setup as a directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angularjs provides jQuery functionality via the `angular.element` function (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element), so you should use it instead of `$` (however, I cannot explain why `$` isn't working in your case)

Comment: Appreciate the help. That solved my problem. It's odd that it works. In other areas I am using `$`. Thanks.